# Invariance of a volume element in phase space: What does it means?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, volume, poisson-brackets

I have been reading the third edition of Classical Mechanics by Goldstein, in particular, chapter 9 Poisson Brackets and Other canonical invariants. And it is shown that the magnitude of a volume element is invariant. I can understand what it means mathematically, but what physical implications does it have?

I have been reading similar questions and noticed that this invariance is related to [Liouville’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)). But I do not understand the underlying physics.

Maybe someone can shed light on this issue.

Comment: The conservation of volume in phase space and Liouville's Theorem are related to the underlying physics statement that physics is **reversible** in time, so two different states cannot evolve to the same state, so that the volume of the states cannot reduce as the states evolve.
I recommend Prof. Susskind's lecture on this topic https://cosmolearning.org/video-lectures/liouvilles-theorem-phase-spaces/ (and it is also explained in his book "The Theoretical Minimum" volume one).